# Installer cannot start the service under User

Tags: service, installation, wix

Installer installs windows service. 
I provide form to user to select one of accounts to start the service:

1. Local service
2. Local System
3. Network System
4. User account

When I select User and enter Domain\Administrator account + pwd during the installation, service cannot be started.

When I select Local Service it started ok. After this I can change manually account to the same Domain\Administrator account and it started ok.
Why such different behavior?
How I can start service during the installation under any users' account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Util Extensions User element.  You can set the CreateUser attribute to no,  the Name attribute to the [PROPERTY] that you are using in your UI for UserName Input and the LogonAsService attribute to yes.   This will instruct WiX to grant your user the LogOnAsService right without having to write a custom action to call ntrights.exe.

Here's a sample as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="5c6b0f52-d024-4f1b-bfae-2dbb96b3ef15">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Setup" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="serviceComponent" />
    </Feature>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Setup">
          <Component Id="serviceComponent" Guid="380bbddd-daa7-0744-517b-37da768f5570">
            <File Id="serviceFile" Source="$(var.WindowsService.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
            <ServiceInstall Id="serviceInstall" Name="WindowsService" DisplayName="WindowsService" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" ErrorControl="ignore" Account=".\serviceaccount" Password="p2Ekutrekac34ph2" />
            <ServiceControl Id="serviceControl" Name="WindowsService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="no" />
              <util:User Id="user" CreateUser ="yes" Name ="serviceaccount" Password="p2Ekutrekac34ph2" LogonAsService="yes" UpdateIfExists="yes" RemoveOnUninstall="yes" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" FailIfExists="no" Domain="[ComputerName]" CanNotChangePassword="yes" Disabled="no" PasswordExpired="no"/> 
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Does this really work? I could not make this to work at the same time as installing the service, since setting privileges seem to be scheduled as a custom action, therefore, happens after the attempt by Wix to install the service. Or am I missing somtehing ?

Comment: I've tested this on clean VM snapshots and didn't have any problems.

Comment: You mean that you could set the privilege to the user account and install the service in the same .msi/Wix installation. Please, could you share your code with me? I've asked a similar question to that effect there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949478/is-using-utiluser-logonasservice-and-serviceinstall-in-the-same-wix-component

Comment: Yes, done it many times. Answer updated with a (tested) sample.

Comment: Thanks. I see it works when creating the service account at the same time as installing the service itself. Still no luck when we just want to update an existing account while installing the service... Thanks for the time taken to update your answer.

Comment: I guess I missed that part of the question. I'll test that angle. Until then, consider this: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/09/different-year-same-problem.html

Comment: Maxime, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue.  I reset my VM, created the user account by hand and then ran the install.  The service still installed and started.  Looking at Local GPO | User Rights  I can see that serviceaccount correctly has the Logon as Service Right.  I'm using WiX 3.6.

Comment: Thanks again for the time taken for investigating and confirm that it definitely should work. Probably an issue either with Windows Server 2012 or WiX 3.7 I'm using. I'll try the resulting msi on other platforms, reverting to WiX 3.6 or, god forbid, using a custom action as suggested. Cheers.

Comment: Development on WiX 3.7 has only barely begun.  I wouldn't be using weekly builds from it yet.  I'll spin up a 2012 VM and try to repro using 3.6.

Comment: I justed tested on 2012 with no problems.  No problems related to LogonAsService user right that is.  I did have a problem that I had compiled my test service to run on .NET 2.0 (only).  Installing the .NET 3.5 Role add the 2.0 CLR and then it worked.  Or I could go back and recompile the service with an app.config that allows it to run on newer CLR's.  The point is, make sure you are defining the problem correctly.  1920 error messages are famous for being useless.

Comment: Christopher, I can confirm this works with WiX 3.6 on Windows Server 2012 as well. Thank you very much for your patience. I could not figure out what I did wrong and it turns out I was using a version of Wix that is still Under too much development. Cheers.

Comment: The solution for me was the .\ in the login name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the selected user account has the right to [log on as a service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx?ppud=4). It doesn't matter if you are an Administrator, you cannot install services for an user without giving him the log on right.

If setting this policy works, you also need to do it dynamically during install. A solution is to use [ntrights.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) as a custom action. This custom action can use your custom properties which contains the user account information.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders why the code from @Christopher Painter his answer didn't work. I had similar code that didn't work with error 1923.

> Error 1923. Service '' () could not be installed.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.
>   MSI (s) (10:08) [15:55:00:161]: Product: '' (64 bit) -- Error 1923. Service '' () could not be installed.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.

Until I found that **services.msc dialog needs to be closed during installation**.

No idea why, but it works.
During development services.msc was open all the time, so I never noticed.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe the services snapin is keeping a lock on the service control manager apis.  I've never heard of this.  Good trivia for me to test some day.   What version and edition of windows were you using?

Comment: Using Windows 10 x64 Pro Anniv.Update.
If you search a bit on Bing you'll find that others had the same problem in the past. e.g. see: https://conetrix.com/Blog/close-servicesmsc-window-to-add-or-remove-services